# Tukey Test in Linear Regression Model Development

Tags: r, regression, interpretation, survey, diagnostic

I am not able to interpret properly the Tukey Test results from a linear regression model i have built. The Tukey Test for the model i believe is to test is the model is linear. Please correct me if i am wrong. We get this Tukey result from residualPlots command in R.

From the Tukey Test, all the variable have a p-value that are non-significant (p>0.05) but the Tukey Test for the entire model is significant (p=000). How can i make the Tukey Test non- significant for the entire model.

Please let me know the approach i need to use to make the tukey test non-significant for the entire model. And also the R codes that will help me here. Thanks.

The data is ordinal survey data. Most of the questions are scaled from 1 to 5. However, i am treating them to be continuous to build an overall model. There are a few variables that are binary 1/0. In total there are 18 independent variables, and three additional transformed variables (i.e. squared).  The sample size is ~2000 observations.

Comment: There are many tests called the "Tukey test" (I could name a handful without even trying). What are you testing, and why perform a hypothesis test for it rather than some other form of  assessment (say some diagnostic display, for example)? What's your sample size? How many predictors? How was the regression model "built"? What do the data consist of (e.g. are they counts? Observations over time? ...)

Comment: Have provided some more details, let me know if this is sufficient. Wanted to load images but i am not able to.

Comment: R itself doesn't have a `residualPlots` command. What package are you using? If you upload images somewhere where the images can be grabbed easily, such as imgur, and give links, someone will be able to fix them up for you. (You can always flag if it doesn't happen)